# BeagleBone Black SD card issues

Tags: linux, storage, sd-card, beaglebone

I am currently booting off of EMMC and I want to use my SD card as external storage for my beaglebone black. However when I plug in the SD card and run the command `df -h`, I can't find the partition for my SD card.

I guess I am missing a step, can anyone help me out with this?

In case you are wondering my system info is:

```
Linux beaglebone 4.4.91-ti-rt-r137 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Tue Nov 7 03:25:55 UTC 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

First familiarize yourself with the hardware:

- `dmesg|tail -20` to get an idea about the last 20 kernel messages.

If the card is already formatted you should be able to just do something like `mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt` (that command is an *example* and might not work!).

Whatever distribution you are running on the BBB probably doesn't have an auto-mounter, so you have to mount the card manually.

If you will leave the card inserted you should consider adding an entry to `/etc/fstab` to have this specific card configuration mounted at boot.